# Companion object with extension function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, companion-object, extension-function, kotlin-companion

I would like to have extension function and use logger from [kotlin-logging](https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging) and have constants inside companion object.

My function:

```
fun String.toFoo(): Foo {

    logger.debug { "Mapping [$this] to Foo" }

    if(MY_CONST.equals(this) { 
        ...
}
```

Question is where I should put `val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}` and `MY_CONST` since I cannot use companion object with an extension function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want you logger to be a singleton you can make an object that contains and instance of the logger and reach it from there.

```
Object LoggerSingleton( val logger = KotlinLogging.logger{})
```

Then in your extension function

```
fun String.toFoo(): Foo {

LoggerSingleton.logger.debug { "Mapping [$this] to Foo" }

if(MY_CONST.equals(this) { 
 }
```

Since an Object in Kotlin is guaranteed to have only one instance you won't have a different logger for each use of toFoo.

**EDIT**
To keep the desired class name
[Use this signature](https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/blob/master/kotlin-logging-jvm/src/main/kotlin/mu/KLogging.kt#L46)
Like so:

```
Object StringLoggerSingleton( val logger = KotlinLogging.logger("String"))
```

Comment: and where to store constants that would be used in extension function?

Comment: If they're really constants then store them inside the function, if they come from a configuration just load them from the config file into a singleton and reference that singleton using the same pattern as the logger.

Comment: Argh, I've just found out that 'kotlin-logging' takes name of class from the context where it's initialized. So making a singleton would hide real class name :(

Comment: Just give it the class name instead of using the lambda signature https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/blob/master/kotlin-logging-jvm/src/main/kotlin/mu/KLogging.kt#L46

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you want to accomplish with your logger, but I show you what I did already ;-)

Usually I put extension functions in its own file named similar to what the function is actually extending (e.g. either `StringExtensionFunction` or if is more related to its purpose and maybe only available if certain dependencies are available, I also did something like, e.g. `JsoupExtensionFunctions` (where there was a `String.toJsoupHtml()`, `File.toJsoupXml()`, etc.)).

If I then need constants I just place them within that file, e.g. by just writing something like:

```
private const val MY_CONST = "my_const_value"
```

No surrounding `class`, no surrounding `object`.

Regarding the `logger`... as loggers are usually tied to a certain name/class, I usually put a logger inside every (important) class or associate some logger to specific names... So I am not completely sure what your intent is here... If it's ok for you that the logger is returning the container of your extension function (maybe `StringExtensionFunction.kt`), then you can also put a logger-val inside that file similar to what I showed with `MY_CONST`.

If your intention was rather to reuse the callers logger, that might not work so easily... (the easiest would then probably be to pass it to the function, but usually you do not want that)... and other mechanisms may not really be worth it ;-)